# Range inside switch case statement in Coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript, handlebars.js

I am using Handlebar in my Rails 3.2 jquery  mobile application.

I am trying to write a switch case statement inside a Coffeescript method like

```
Handlebars.registerHelper 'status', (blog) ->
  switch(parseInt(blog.status))
    when [0..20]
      status = "active"
    when [20..40]
      status = "Moderately Active"
    when [40..60]
      status = "Very Active"
    when [60..100]
      status = "Hyper Active"
  return status
```

I am not getting any result . How to use range in when . Please suggest

Comment: Why would this work? This [github issue](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/1383) seems to say that this syntax was not accepted.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your `switch` won't work as [Cygal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/481584/cygal) notes in the comments (i.e. see [issue 1383](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/1383)). A `switch` is just a glorified `if(a == b)` construct and you need to be able to say things like:

```
a = [1,2,3]
switch a
...
```

and have it work when you `switch` on an array. The CoffeeScript designers thought adding a (fragile) special case to handle arrays (which is all `[a..b]` is) specially wasn't worth it.

You can do it with an `if`:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper 'status', (blog) ->
  status = parseInt(blog.status, 10)
  if 0 <= status <= 20
    'Active'
  else if 20 < status <= 40
    'Moderately Active'
  else if 40 < status <= 60
    'Very Active'
  else if 60 < status <= 100
    'Hyper Active'
  else
    # You need to figure out what to say here
```

Or with short circuiting `return`s like this:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper 'status', (blog) ->
  status = parseInt(blog.status, 10)
  return 'Something...'      if status <=   0
  return 'Active'            if status <=  20
  return 'Moderately Active' if status <=  40
  return 'Very Active'       if status <=  60
  return 'Hyper Active'      if status <= 100
  return 'Something else'    # This return isn't necessary but I like the symmetry
```

Note that you have three special cases that you need to add strings for:

1. `status < 0`.
2. `status > 100`.
3. `status` is `NaN`. This case would usually fall under the final "it isn't less than or equal to 100" branch since `NaN => n` and `NaN <= n` are both false for all `n`.

Yes, you're absolutely certain that the status will always fall within the assumed range. On the other hand, the impossible happens all the time software (hence the comp.risks mailing list) and there's no good reason to leave holes that are so easily filled.

Also note the addition of the radix argument to the [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) call, you wouldn't want a leading zero to make a mess of things. Yes, the radix argument is optional but it really shouldn't be and your fingers should automatically add the `, 10` to every `parseInt` call you make.

Comment: Such a good answer :D. I like the succinctness of the second solution but also like the "all-is-an-expressionability" of the first one. May i propose to join both [using a `swtich <nothing>` expression](http://goo.gl/QKKAq)? =D (i don't want to steal any points posting that as a new answer)

Comment: @epidemian: That looks like a good alternative to me, I have many points and I don't mind sharing so you should put it down as an answer. I'd probably use the second, I like the "it is an inlined lookup table" effect.

Comment: OK, i added an answer as an appendix of yours.

Comment: Software fails all the time, but I tend to stick to this Erlang rule in all languages: [Don't program defensively](http://www.erlang.se/doc/programming_rules.shtml#HDR11). Defensive programming makes debugging way harder.

Comment: @Cygal: I don't see the mandatory "It depends" rule in that list :) I tend to prefer the "fail loudly and make sure someone knows about it" approach, the second part of that is difficult in a browser.

Comment: Sure, the point is to fail loudly if I understand it correctly. It's possible to report exceptions back to the server by the way.

Answer (score 8):

Adding a tiny bit to [mu is too short's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11202858/581845), you can transform its second code snippet into a `switch` expression:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper 'status', (blog) ->
  status = parseInt(blog.status, 10)
  switch
    when status <= 0   then 'Something...'      
    when status <= 20  then 'Active'
    when status <= 40  then 'Moderately Active'
    when status <= 60  then 'Very Active'
    when status <= 100 then 'Hyper Active'
    else 'Something else'
```

This is basically equivalent to doing a `switch (true)` in JavaScript (though the CS compiler will generate a [`switch (false)` statement with the negated conditions](http://coffeescript.org/#try:Handlebars.registerHelper%20%27status%27%2C%20%28blog%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20status%20%3D%20parseInt%28blog.status%2C%2010%29%0A%20%20switch%0A%20%20%20%20when%20status%20%3C%3D%20%20%200%20then%20%27Something...%27%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20when%20status%20%3C%3D%20%2020%20then%20%27Active%27%0A%20%20%20%20when%20status%20%3C%3D%20%2040%20then%20%27Moderately%20Active%27%0A%20%20%20%20when%20status%20%3C%3D%20%2060%20then%20%27Very%20Active%27%0A%20%20%20%20when%20status%20%3C%3D%20100%20then%20%27Hyper%20Active%27%0A%20%20%20%20else%20%27Something%20else%27) to ensure boolean results from the expressions... i think).

---

And the reason why the `switch` over ranges doesn't work is that ranges literals in CS represent plain old JS arrays (though the compiler will do some optimization tricks when doing something like `for i in [1..something]`), so when they are found inside a `switch` they are treated just [like normal array values](http://coffeescript.org/#try:Handlebars.registerHelper%20%27status%27%2C%20%28blog%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20switch%28parseInt%28blog.status%29%29%0A%20%20%20%20when%20[0..20]%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20status%20%3D%20%22active%22%0A%20%20%20%20when%20[20..40]%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20status%20%3D%20%22Moderately%20Active%22%0A%20%20%20%20when%20[40..60]%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20status%20%3D%20%22Very%20Active%22%0A%20%20%20%20when%20[60..100]%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20status%20%3D%20%22Hyper%20Active%22%0A%20%20return%20status):

```
// Generated JS for question's CS code:
switch (parseInt(blog.status)) {
  case [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]:
    status = "active";
    break;
  case [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40]:
    status = "Moderately Active";
    break;
  case [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60]:
    status = "Very Active";
    break;
  case (function() {
      _results = [];
      for (_i = 60; _i <= 100; _i++){ _results.push(_i); }
      return _results;
    }).apply(this):
    status = "Hyper Active";
}
```

The value inside the `switch` statement is basically compared to each `case` value using `===`, which only works for primitives, not for arrays (and even if it worked for arrays, it would be testing array equality, not if the `switch`ed value is contained in the `case`ed arrays).

Comment: See, that was worth doing. I wouldn't have thought of that form of `switch` but next time I will. I think you're right but the boolean context and using `switch(false)` instead of `switch(true)`.